# How to modify the gasLimit of the private block chain on the console

Tags: go-ethereum, ether, cpp-ethereum, ethereum-classic, golang

as the title,How to modify the "gasLimit" of the private block chain on the console?

Answer (score 2):

you could use geth with the option `--targetgaslimit`.

`--targetgaslimit` value  Target gas limit sets the artificial target gas floor for the blocks to mine (default: "4712388").